# Fix shell script to increment semversion

Tags: bash, shell, awk, semantic-versioning

I've never work with shell (bash), but found some bug in script, that I used to increment version. Script works fine, until this case

```
version=1.27.9
echo $version | awk -F. -v OFS=. 'NF==1{print ++$NF}; NF>1{if(length($NF+1)>length($NF))$(NF-1)++; $NF=sprintf("%0*d", length($NF), ($NF+1)%(10^length($NF))); print}'

1.28.0  <-- result, but I need 1.27.10
```

In this case `new_version` will be equals to `1.28.0`. How to change this script to avoid incrementing MINOR number?  For this case I expecting `1.27.10`

I've no experience in shell, so don't know where to start. I found this script here, on SO and use it. Please help me to solve my problem.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***EDIT:*** To change only MINOR version try following.

```
echo "$version" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} {$3+=1} 1'
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation to above code.

```
echo "$version" |           ##using echo to print variable version value here and passing it to awk program.
awk '                       ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                      ##Starting BEGIN section of this awk program here.
  FS=OFS="."                ##Setting FS and OFS as dot(.) here for all lines of Input_file.
}
{
  $3+=1                     ##For every line of Input_file adding 1 to 3rd field and saving output to $3 itself.
}
1                           ##Mentioning 1 will print edited/non-edited lines here.
'
```

---

---

Could you please try following, to change middle version as per last(minor) version which OP confirmed not needed but which I understood at very first glance of this requirement.

```
echo "$version" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} {$3+=1;if($3>9){$2+=1;$3=0}} 1'
```

Comment: the same result - `1.28.0`, I need `1.27.10` when version was `1.27.9`

Comment: @Chebur, ahhh I thought vice versa :) lemme fix it right away.

Comment: @Chebur, Please check my EDIT solution and lemme know if this helps you?

Comment: Thank you very match. You are superhero, how do you know what's going on here  `{$3+=1}`  :) Crazy expression for me `$3+=1;if($3>9){$2+=1;$3=0` )))

Comment: @Chebur, thanks for compliment :)  `$3+=1` is adding 1 to last field and saving its result into 3rd field itself, lemme add complete explanation in few mins and will let you know on same.

Comment: @Chebur, Could you please go through my added explanation and lemme know if there is any query.

Comment: "To change only MINOR version try following." You mean PATCH?

Answer (score 6):

A pure Bash solution:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

version='1.27.9'

# Read Semver fields
IFS=. read -r major minor patch <<<"$version"

# Increment patch version
# same as patch="$((patch + 1))"
((patch++))

# Re-assemble version string from Semver fields
printf -v version '%d.%d.%d' "$major" "$minor" "$((patch))"
```

- `IFS=.`; Sets the field separator to `.` in the local scope of the `read` command.
- `read -r major minor patch <<<"$version"`: Reads Semver fields from the `"$version` here-string.
- `((patch++))`: Increments the `$patch` version using Bash's stand-alone arithmetic. (Can be replaced by `patch="$((patch + 1))"`)
- `printf -v version '%d.%d.%d' "$major" "$minor" "$((patch))"`: Formats the `$version` string with updated fields, using Bash's `printf -v variable` (output to variable) feature.

A short-hand one-line equivalent to [@RavinderSingh13 's version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59435668/7939871):

`IFS=. read -r a b c<<<"$version";echo "$a.$b.$((c+1))"`

Or a POSIX one-liner:

```sh
OIFS="$IFS";IFS=.;set -- $version;echo "$1.$2.$((10#$3+1))";IFS="$OIFS";set --
```

- `OIFS="$IFS"`: Saves the **I**nternal **F**ield **S**eparator.
- `IFS=.`: Set the dot as Field Separator.
- `set -- $version`: Splits the version string into arguments, using the `IFS`.
- `echo "$1.$2.$((10#$3+1))"`: Prints the upgraded minor Semver `10#$3` with specifying base 10 for 3<sup>rd</sup> argument.
- `IFS="$OIFS"`: Restores the `IFS` to its original value.
- `set --`: Clears the arguments array.

Comment: $((patch++))
bash: 9: command not found

Comment: @Chebur fixed issue by removing the `$` in front of the stand-alone arithmetic. Also added alternative method.